# Changing the child element's CSS when the parent is hovered

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, parent

First of all, I'm assuming this is too complex for CSS3, but if there's a solution in there somewhere, I'd love to go with that instead.

The HTML is pretty straightforward.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Text Block 1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Text Block 2
    </div>
</div>
```

The child div is set to display:none; by default, but then changes to display:block; when the mouse is hovered over the parent div. The problem is that this markup appears in several places on my site, and I only want the child to be displayed if the mouse is over it's parent, and not if the mouse is over any of the other parents (they all have the same class name and no IDs).

I've tried using `$(this)` and `.children()` to no avail.

```
$('.parent').hover(function(){
            $(this).children('.child').css("display","block");
        }, function() {
            $(this).children('.child').css("display","none");
        });
```

Answer (score 335, accepted):

Why not just use CSS?

```
.parent:hover .child, .parent.hover .child { display: block; }
```

and then add JS for IE6 (inside a conditional comment for instance) which doesn't support :hover properly:

```
jQuery('.parent').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('hover');
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Here's a quick example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5FLr4/)

Comment: that code isn't working for me. is it supposed to say ".parent.hover" and not ".parent:hover"?? case i've never seen what you have before. and doesn't a comma indicate multiple selectors taking the same styles? i don't see how that helps here. a little more info on that CSS, por favor 0=]

Comment: `:hover` is one of the "Dynamic pseudo-classes" defined by CSS2 ([here's the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)).  Here's a quick example: [http://jsfiddle.net/5FLr4/](http://jsfiddle.net/5FLr4/). it works for me.

Comment: ahh thanks so much! i actually had some relative positioning that was pushing the child text out of view... doh! >.< i appreciate the help!

Comment: Apparently this won't work for .child::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb if you want to change the highlight of the scrollbar inside the child element.

Comment: `.parent:not(:hover) .child { display: none; }` seems to work well for me, though I'm certainly not worried about IE6.  But this way I can use it on elements that I don't want to have a uniform `display` property.

Comment: It does exactly what I'm looking for except its chaging all the child elements not only the one which is hovered over

Comment: @MarekBarta why don't you just use the :hover on the child element then? What you are seeing is what was asked!

Comment: If you still have any problems here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Yasserchenik/dqkhnzLf/10/)

Answer (score 203):

No need to use the JavaScript or jquery, CSS is enough:

```
.child{ display:none; }
.parent:hover .child{ display:block; }
```

[**SEE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/u0yrrnt2/)

Answer (score 20):

```
.parent:hover > .child {
    /*do anything with this child*/
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `toggleClass()`.

```
$('.parent').hover(function(){
$(this).find('.child').toggleClass('color')
});
```

where `color` is the class. You can style the class as you like to achieve the behavior you want. The example demonstrates how class is added and removed upon mouse in and out.

### Check Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaHz8/2/).

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if there's terrible reasons to do this or not, but it seems to work with me on the latest version of Chrome/Firefox without any visible performance problems with quite a lot of elements on the page.

```
*:not(:hover)>.parent-hover-show{
    display:none;
}
```

But this way, all you need is to apply `parent-hover-show` to an element and the rest is taken care of, and you can keep whatever default display type you want without it always being "block" or making multiple classes for each type.

Answer (score 4):

To change it from css you dont even need to set the child class

```
.parent > div:nth-child(1) { display:none; }
.parent:hover > div:nth-child(1) { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 3):

[Stephen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061940/changing-the-child-elements-css-when-the-parent-is-hovered-with-jquery/5061953#5061953) is correct but here's my adaptation of his answer:

#### HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <p> parent 1 </p>
    <div class="child">
        Text Block 1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <p> parent 2 </p>
    <div class="child">
        Text Block 2
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.parent { width: 100px; min-height: 100px; color: red; }
.child { width: 50px; min-height: 20px; color: blue; display: none; }
.parent:hover .child, .parent.hover .child { display: block; }
```

#### jQuery

```
//this is only necessary for IE and should be in a conditional comment

jQuery('.parent').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('hover');
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

You can see this example [working over at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qt9vr/).

Answer (score 3):

I have what i think is a better solution, since it is scalable to more levels, as many as wanted, not only two or three.

I use borders, but it can also be done with whateever style wanted, like background-color.

With the border, the idea is to:

- Have a different border color only one div, the div over where the mouse is, not on any parent, not on any child, so it can be seen only such div border in a different color while the rest stays on white.

You can test it at: http://jsbin.com/ubiyo3/13

And here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Hierarchie Borders MarkUp</title>
<style>

  .parent { display: block; position: relative; z-index: 0;
            height: auto; width: auto; padding: 25px;
          }

  .parent-bg { display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; 
               position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; 
               border: 1px solid white; z-index: 0; 
             }
  .parent-bg:hover { border: 1px solid red; }

  .child { display: block; position: relative; z-index: 1; 
           height: auto; width: auto; padding: 25px;
         }

  .child-bg { display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; 
              position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; 
              border: 1px solid white; z-index: 0; 
            }
  .child-bg:hover { border: 1px solid red; }

  .grandson { display: block; position: relative; z-index: 2; 
              height: auto; width: auto; padding: 25px;
            }

  .grandson-bg { display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; 
                 position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; 
                 border: 1px solid white; z-index: 0; 
               }
  .grandson-bg:hover { border: 1px solid red; }

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    Parent
    <div class="child">
      Child
      <div class="grandson">
        Grandson
        <div class="grandson-bg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="child-bg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent-bg"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the question asked. It changes the border around the element that is hovered over.  Not the border around a child element.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) styling and base JS for a drop down menu:

```
.child{ display:none; }
.parent:hover .child{ display:block; }
```

This is the missing piece to create sticky-dropdowns (that aren't annoying)

- The behavior is to:

  1. Stay open when clicked, close when clicking again anywhere else on the page
  2. Close automatically when the mouse scrolls out of the menu's elements.

Answer (score 0):

What did work for me was nth-of-type to target an specific element, a SVG icon and instead of using display:none; to avoid not finding it later, I used the fill color as the background color, so white in this case and then to target with css the parent and finding directly the SVG element with :nth-type-of(1)

**HTML**

```
<div class="feature-col">
<div class="feature-icon bg-primary bg-dark" style="border:0.125em white">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" fill="white" class="bi bi-laptop" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M13.5 3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V11H2V3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11zm-11-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 3.5V12h14V3.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 13.5 2h-11zM0 12.5h16a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-13A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 12.5z"></path>
</svg>
</div>
<h5>Website Design and Hosting</h5>
<p>Some text in here that is a child element as well...</p>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon-link">Call to action</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.feature-col:hover svg:nth-of-type(1){
fill: #FF5B0D;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

JSFIDDLE to play with:
https://jsfiddle.net/93de7zbc/6/

Answer (score 0):

#### Using CSS Visibility property

Try to use the CSS visibility property to keep with the size div to be possible to hover the element:
Using CSS Sibling

```css
      .text {
        visibility: hidden;
        margin: 10px;
      }
      .sibling {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .sibling:hover + .text {
        visibility: visible;
      }
```

```html
    <h3 class="sibling">
      Hover me to show the sibling content
    </h3>
    <div class="text">Text Block 1</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution does only display the child, if the mouse is over the child. I and the OP required this "I only want the child to be displayed if the mouse is over it's parent".

Comment: @user3772108 I've changed it to be possible achieve the sibling element when hovering the label