# CSS-only hover over div un-hides text on CodePen, but not on my WP site.

Tags: css, hover

I'm trying to set up a div that shows text over an image when you hover over it. It works fine on CodePen, but not on my WordPress site. I tried playing with some of the CSS, but none of the things I tried ended up working. Site under construction. Any suggestions?

Here is the code for CodePen: http://codepen.io/Clare12345/pen/RWoxRB. Also works on Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Clare12345/yxap7n30/
:/

The HTML:

```
    <div class="container">

        <div class="sep">

            <div class="image-hover img-layer-image-hover-backgroundchange">
                <img src="http://www.plici.ro/images/3-1386110366.jpg">
                <div class="layer">this text should appear on hover</div>
            </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
/****** image hover ******/

.image-hover * {-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
.image-hover { position:relative;width:450px;height:200px;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:#fff;border:10px solid #fff;box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);-moz-box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);-webkit-box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)}
.image-hover a { text-decoration: none; }

/*** effect layer-image hover - background change ***/
.img-layer-image-hover-backgroundchange .layer { position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px;opacity:0.6;background-color:#000;background-image:url("icons/lupe.png");background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center}
.img-layer-image-hover-backgroundchange:hover .layer {opacity:0.5;background-color:#fff;
}
.img-layer-image-hover-backgroundchange .layer {
transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.img-layer-image-hover-backgroundchange:hover .layer {
transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Well... in this case - link would be fine.

Comment: @nevermind the site is under construction. Maybe I can set it up on a WordPress site that's not under construction just for this purpose. I'll post back if I get that set up.

Comment: Figured it out. Added answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I figured it out. It turns out I needed to set the child div to show when hovering over the parent and display none the child when not being hovered over.

This helped: [Changing the child element's CSS when the parent is hovered with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061940/changing-the-child-elements-css-when-the-parent-is-hovered-with-jquery) (Just the CSS portion, not the first answer)

Thank you!!!