# How to underline some words when scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, underline

I am busy with a site [here](http://dev.appronto.nl/home/#vacature) and I want to underline some words in different colors when scrolling over a section as attached.

[image]

1 - How can I reach such effect?

2 - And if I want to show a icon (font awesome) when scrolling, would that be similar?

thanks

Comment: I think you're searching for something like [this](http://codepen.io/Kseso/pen/bfzjC). A quick google can solve questions like these..

Comment: Thanks, I know how to underline a word, but I want that this particular class gets fired when I am hoovering another, bigger class...I think some jquery /js is needed for this?

Comment: No, [you don't have to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5061953/3880255). And **please** learn how to properly utilize google, your question's solution can be found on google in less than two minutes.

Comment: Thanks Tarekis, I am a beginner and need coaching with my own code. I put [my code in this example](https://jsfiddle.net/te9qrjLn/2/)...Can you teach me how to fire all the childs when I am hoovering on parent in stead of hoovering over childs one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine [this](http://codepen.io/Kseso/pen/bfzjC) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5061953/3880255) to get a proper result.

Change your selector for the `:before` elements to this:

```
.parent:hover .hvr-underline-from-left:before
```

Now this CSS applies when the parent is hovered.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/c2xd1sy1/)

Answer (score -1):

Here have the html and js code to do it.

```css
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>GETTING STARTED WITH BRACKETS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              
            });
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                 $("#words").css('text-decoration','underline');
            });
       
       
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <p id="words">
                sdfgdsjafaghdf
            </p>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: NO need for JS, also no dependencies so it fires when the user scrolls over the element, and a change in css is really bad, at least change classes..